# How to level two different floor heights to prepare for carpet?

Tags: subfloor

We have a second floor bedroom that was added onto the old house a long time ago and it is 1.25" lower than the hallway.  The bedroom currently has hardwoods.

What is the best way to raise the floor to meet the hallway hardwoods and install carpet?
--- 2 layers of OSB plywood? is there a weight issue with this?
--- Install sleepers and then a layer of OSB?
--- leave the hardwoods and install a transition piece

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do 1/2" sleepers (could be ripped from plywood or OSB) directly over the joists, then 3/4" t&g subflooring with construction adhesive between everything to prevent squeaks. Use screws or ring-shank nails long enough to penetrate the existing subfloor and joist at least 1-1/2".

Weight shouldn't be an issue, but I know nothing about your home's construction.

Answer (score 0):

Since we're only talking 1-1/4" difference, I'd install a reducer and be done with it... Any more than that, I'd go with @isherwood's method. Sleepers + subfloor already puts you 1/4" over the existing floor level, then you have to deal with finish flooring, vinyl, tile, etc., on top of that... Then you'll have to reduce down to the existing floor... So basically, it's a catch 22...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my miscalculation. I've revised to indicate 1/2" sleepers.